# New profile view on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

We recently have a [new profile view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3820025/battlehamster) on Stack Overflow.
I have two questions about this.

1. Will it be introduced on more Stack Exchange communities in the near future?
2. I do not know if it is a suitable question for Meta, if not where can I ask questions like this one?

Comment: "Will it be introduced on more stack exchange communities in the near future?" - It already is introduced on most other SE communities (at least on all where I have an account), I'm not sure there's a community where it's not introduced yet. It was introduced first on meta.SE a while ago.

Comment: Well, there are sites where it has not been introduced yet. Like [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). But it seems to me then, it is in progress.

Comment: Maybe that's due to the more complex header of those sites - seems like that could be tough to integrate with the new profile design.

Comment: As for the second part of my question. Did you find my question unnecessary or useless, and do you think it should be removed?

Comment: Well, asking when the feature will be rolled out to other sites is a valid question, but the answer will probably be something generic - there was no fixed timeline for SO either, only the default "6-8 weeks" (which basically means "when it's done").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Will it be introduced on more stack exchange communities in the near future?

In [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) you can see:

> Some of you may have noticed that [we just launched](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/) the [new
> profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) and [activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) pages that we have been talking about
> for a while now on [most Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).

Then,

> 2. I do not know if it is a suitable question for Meta, if not where can I ask questions like this one?

You better ask in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) adding the [profile-page] tag to your question. There are already [some of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profile-page) about it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be introduced on more sites in the network. From the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1) that announced the change:

> *Any*way, as of today, it’s live on SO and about [half the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), and we’ll be rolling out to the rest over the next few weeks.